# Distinct when values can be interchangeable between columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query -

```
select distinct v.npi1, v.npi2, 
count(*)
from hcpc cross join lateral
     (values (f_rend, f_bill), (f_rend, t_rend), (f_rend, t_bill), (f_bill, t_rend), 
     (f_bill, t_bill), (t_rend, t_bill)
     ) v(npi1, npi2)
     where 
     npi1 <> npi2
     and npi1 <> ''
     and npi2 <> ''
     group by v.npi1, v.npi2
```

It is producing results like this -

```
npi1    npi2        count
1033543 1295706         8
1225257 129570666       1
1295706 1033543         17
```

How do I get this result instead -

```
npi1    npi2        count
1033543 1295706         25
1225257 129570666       1
```

This is because line 1 and 3 are the same values (They are just in different columns).

Comment: try a union instead.  idea is to union the columns into a single column - then do your distinct.

Comment: Can there be more than 1 dupe number? Why the first row of the dupe is kept and not the second?

Comment: @Randy I can't union them into a single column because the relationship would be lost if I did that

Comment: @Bohemian I don't care if we keep the second as long as only one of them is kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` to get the two values sorted.

```
select
  least(v.npi1, v.npi2) as value1,
  greatest(v.npi1, v.npi2) as value2,
  count(*)
from hcpc cross join lateral
     (values (f_rend, f_bill), (f_rend, t_rend), (f_rend, t_bill), (f_bill, t_rend), 
     (f_bill, t_bill), (t_rend, t_bill)
     ) v(npi1, npi2)
where npi1 <> npi2
  and npi1 <> ''
  and npi2 <> ''
group by least(v.npi1, v.npi2), greatest(v.npi1, v.npi2)
order by value1, value2;
```

Comment: What if there are more than 2 numbers involved, and the dupe number is neither the least nor the greatest?

Comment: Then you can probably put them in an array and sort that. I am not sure, though.